# whereHas is not working properly. I want to search by location name, which is not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have two table customers, locations, and pivot table customer_location. I want to display Customer with id 3 with location, and then I can search that by location's name, customer's name, domain, number, or by email.

```
public function getCustomersProperty()
{
    $search = $this->search;
    
    return Customer::with('locations')->where('id', '=', '3')
        ->whereHas('locations', function ($q) use ($search) {
            $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
        })
        ->where(function ($q) {
            $q->Where('name', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
                ->orWhere('domain', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
                ->orWhere('number', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
                ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%');
        })
        ->orderBy($this->sortField, $this->sortDirection)
        ->paginate($this->page_number);
}
```

Comment: define "not working". Do you get an error? Unwanted results? What does `dump($this->search);` output?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean search by location OR anything else from those fields

```
public function getCustomersProperty()
{
    $search= $this->search;
    return Customer::with('locations')->where('id', '=', '3')
        ->where(function($q) {
            $q->Where('name','like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
                ->orWhere('domain','like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
                ->orWhere('number','like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
                ->orWhere('email','like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
                ->orWhereHas('locations', function($q) use($search) {
                    $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
                });

        })
        ->orderBy($this->sortField, $this->sortDirection)
        ->paginate($this->page_number);
}
```

Or you wanted the eager loaded locations to be relevant to your search.

```
public function getCustomersProperty()
{
    $search= $this->search;
    return Customer::with(['locations' => function($q) use($search) {
            $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
        }])
        ->where('id', '=', '3')
        ->whereHas('locations', function($q) use($search) {
            $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
        })
        ->where(function($q) {
            $q->Where('name','like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
                ->orWhere('domain','like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
                ->orWhere('number','like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
                ->orWhere('email','like', '%'.$this->search.'%');
        })
        ->orderBy($this->sortField, $this->sortDirection)
        ->paginate($this->page_number);
}
```